# Setting a max width for LinearLayout

Tags: android, user-interface, layout

How can I set the max width of my horizontal `LinearLayout`? So if the contents are short (say, some text), the layout shrinks and if the contents are longer, it will not expand more than some max width value.

I prefer doing this at the XML level.

Comment: see my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8619442/236743) for another approach using a ViewGroup subclass

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This does it - what I needed [beyond what was suggested in prior answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3702533/839601) is to add another layout (`@+id/TheLayout`) as a wrapper between the content and the top layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:paddingLeft="100dip"
android:paddingRight="100dip">
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:id="@+id/TheLayout"
    android:layout_gravity="right">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/TextView01" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="this is my text." 
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">
    </TextView>
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/ImageView01"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:background="@drawable/icon"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent">
    </ImageView>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Nice! Working like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    int widthMaxSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(270 /*pixels*/, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
    super.onMeasure(widthMaxSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
}
```

Comment: welcome to SO, you'd rather explain why your code will solve his problem, thanks.