# Tablet layout limit width in elements

Tags: android, layout, tablet

I have an app that runs on both layout and handset. Some screens use fragments and everything works properly. The problem is in some activities like the login one.

I would like to constraint the width of the elements in signin page to a certain maximum width in order to not make it stretch (making it looks not natural).

Is there a clean solution besides creating new layouts?

Thanks
Tobia Loschiavo

Comment: I think this is exactly what you are looking for: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5875877/setting-max-width-of-linearlayout-or-other-viewgroup-on-android

Comment: Great...why isn't it a standard solution in android?

Comment: Must have some thought in it. they imlemented an maxWidth attribute especially for imageView instead of just View: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html